# Objective C: simple MKMapkit examples?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

Looking for simple MKMapkit examples for google maps to place pins down and give info if the pin is tapped.

Many of the examples I have run through don't work and the ones that do are just massive code.

Appreciate any help and reference material or books I should look at that simplify things.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excellent book *iPhone Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide* contains an easy to understand example app. Example code is available on the [Big Nerd Ranch website](http://bignerdranch.com/book/iphone_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide). BTW, if you're just starting iPhone development, definitely check the book out. I found it very helpful and worth its money.

Comment: Thank you. I found an example that is simple(relatively) and works.      On a number of them, when I build, I get an Error ==> "Can't run 'Whereami' - was built for 'armv7', but device requires 'armv6' or compatible architecture."  I have come across this before but not sure if there is an easy fix??

Comment: @jdl In Xcode 4, click on your project on the left, then choose *Build Settings*, enable *All*, and under *Architectures* -> *Valid Architectures*, add *armv6*.

Comment: The setting were already set:  Architectures:  Standard (armv6 armv7);   Valid Architectures:  armv6 armv7. Sorry, I should had said that earlier.  My iPod is running 4.2.  But the date on the code-example suggests there should not be a problem.

Comment: @jdl Hmm. No, it shouldn't. Sorry, I'm not very experienced with build settings. The project shouldn't be that large; maybe it's easiest to just start a new Window-Based application, and copy all the code there.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am trying to copy and past the code in a new project.  But it works in the simulator!